# Two equivalent definitions of projective module $P$ (one involving right inverse), how do we make sense of these "replacements" in the proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation, modules, projective-module

I'm going through Rosenberg's *Algebraic K-theory and its applications*.  The following is a screenshot from the first few pages.

The definition of projective left $R$-module $P$ is: for any surjective hom $\alpha: M \twoheadrightarrow P$ there exists a right inverse $\beta : P \to M$ (i.e. such that $\alpha \circ \beta = \text{id}_P$).

The goal is to show that this is equivalent to the usual definition of projective module given in commutative diagrams at the top of the screenshot (i.e. that a commutative triangle can be completed for any surjection $\psi: M \twoheadrightarrow N$ and any hom $\varphi: P \to N$).

[image: Equivalent definitions of projective module proof screenshot]

At the bottom of the screenshot it says we may replace $N$ by $\text{im}((\varphi, \text{id}_P))$ and $M$ by $\psi^{-1}(\text{im}(\varphi))$.  Firstly, do they mean replace the $N$ in $N \oplus P$ or the original $N$ (alone).  And, I don't understand how this will be the same problem as the original, so could you explain this section to me in detail?  Alternatively can you give a proof with more clarity?

Comment: Your  definition is wrong: the right inverse exists for any surjective homomorphism from $M$ to $P$, not the other way.

Comment: To see the proposed definition is wrong, consider $\mathbb{Z}$, which is a projective $\mathbb{Z}$-module (being free), and the surjection $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. This surjection does not have a right inverse.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I'm not proposing a definition.  This is straight from the book.

Comment: @Bernard fixed that in the post

Comment: @StudySmarterNotHarder: I did not say *you* were proposing the definition. I was saying that whoever proposed it made an error in the way it was stated. Whether the error was in the book or in your copying was something not addressed.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin is it corrected now?  I changed the direction of the arrow in error, lol.

Comment: Yes; I’m writing an answer explaining what they are instructing you to do, and why I think it’s needlessly complicated and how to do it more directly.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks, that would be much appreciated.  I fell in love with this book, but maybe it's out of reach for me at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final paragraph is less than clear, so it is no wonder you are a bit confused. Taken literally it might lead you astray (I will note where below). Also, this seems needlessly complicated to me, so I will indicate an alternative argument below after explaining what they are doing.

You are trying to prove that if every surjection onto $P$ has a right inverse, then the module $P$ is projective; that is, that whenever you have a surjection $M\to N$ and a map from $P$ to $N$, you can factor that map through $M$.

So, let $\psi\colon M\to N$ be a surjection, and let $\phi\colon P\to N$ be a map. We want to show that there exists a morphism $\theta\colon P\to M$ such that $\phi=\psi\circ\theta$.

To that end, we will construct a surjection onto $P$ whose right inverse will help us find $\theta$.

Let’s take the module $M\oplus P$, and map it to the module $N\oplus P$ by the map $(\psi,\mathrm{id}_P)$. This map takes $(m,p)$ and sends it to $(\psi(m),p)$. This is a surjection, since $\phi$ and $\mathrm{id}_P$ are surjections: given $n\in N$ and $p\in P$, there exists $m\in M$ such that $\psi(m)=n$, and then $(m,p)$ maps to $(n,p)$.

Let us also replace the morphism $P\to N$ with the morphism $P\to N\oplus P$ given by $(\phi,\mathrm{id}_P)$. This map takes $p\in P$ to $(\phi(p),p)$. Now we have a new diagram:
$$\begin{array}{ccl}
&&P\\
&&\downarrow(\phi,\mathrm{id}_P)\\
M\oplus P&\stackrel{(\psi,\mathrm{id}_P)}{\longrightarrow} & N\oplus P
\end{array}$$
Note that the vertical arrow is now one-to-one: for given $p\in P$, if $(\psi,\mathrm{id}_P)(p) = (0,0)$, then $p=0$.

Now we will replace this diagram yet again; it is here that they are less than clear. Taken literally, we would replace $N$ and $M$, but in fact we will replace $N\oplus P$ and $M\oplus P$:
instead of $N\oplus P$, let us put $\mathrm{Im}(\psi,\mathrm{id}_P)= N’$ (for ease; but note that this is a submodule of $N\oplus P$); and instead of $M\oplus P$, we will put $(\psi,\mathrm{id}_P)^{-1}(N’)$.
$$\begin{array}{ccl}
&&P\\
&&\downarrow(\phi,\mathrm{id}_P)\\
(\psi,\mathrm{id}_P)^{-1}(N’)&\stackrel{(\psi,\mathrm{id}_P)}{\longrightarrow} &N’
\end{array}$$
Note that the bottom arrow is still surjective, and the vertical arrow is still injective (the latter is just a restriction of the previous vertical arrow). But now the vertical arrow is an isomorphism: it is surjective by construction. So the vertical arrow is now an isomorphism.

So now we have a surjection
$$(\psi,\mathrm{id}_P)^{-1}(N’)\stackrel{(\psi,\mathrm{id}_P)}{\longrightarrow} N’\stackrel{(\phi,\mathrm{id}_P)^{-1}}{\longrightarrow} P.$$
We can take the inverse at the end because the restriction of $(\phi,\mathrm{id}_P)$ was an isomorphism.

This composition is a surjection, so it has a right inverse $\beta\colon P\to (\psi,\mathrm{id}_P)^{-1}(N’)\leq M\oplus P$. We claim that if you take this $\beta$ we will get the extension we want to start with (that is, the map $P\to M$ we are looking for); well, not *quite* this extension, but rather $\pi_M\circ\beta\colon P\to M$.

To verify this, take $p\in P$. The $\beta(p)$ has the property that $(\phi,\mathrm{id}_P)\circ(\psi,\mathrm{id}_P)^{-1}(\beta(p))=p$. So $\beta(p)=(m,q)$ for some $m\in M$ and $q\in P$. Then $(\phi(m),q)$ must be equal to $(\psi(p),p)$. Thus, $q=p$, and $\psi(p) = \phi(m)=\phi(\pi_M(\beta(p)))$.

Thus, $\pi_M\circ\beta\colon P\to M$ has the property that $\phi(\pi_M\circ\beta(p))=\psi(p)$, hence this is the morphism we are looking for.

---

Now, I think the instructions to replace and replace again are a little too complicated (as may be apparent above). We can do all of the above without so much be using a free module as an auxiliary. This uses a third equivalent condition to being free:

**Theorem.** Suppose that $P$ is a module such that every surjection $M\to P$ has a right inverse. Then there exists a module $Q$ such that $Q\oplus P$ is free.

*Proof.* Let $F$ be a free module that surjects onto $P$ (this is always possible; e.g., you can take the free module on the underlying set of $P$), $\pi\colon F\to P$. Then this surjection has a right inverse $\beta\colon P\to F$. Since $\pi\beta=\mathrm{id}_P$, then $\beta$ is injective. Now let $Q=\mathrm{ker}(\pi)$. If $x\in Q\cap \beta(P)$, then $x=\beta(p)$, so $0=\pi(x)=\pi(\beta(p))=p$. Thus, $Q\cap\beta(P)=\{0\}$. Now let $x\in F$. then $x-\beta(\pi(x))\in Q$, $\beta(\pi(x))\in \beta(P)$, so $x=\beta(\pi(x))+ (x-\beta(\pi(x)) \in \beta(P)+Q$. Thus, $F=\beta(P)\oplus Q\cong P\oplus Q$, as desired. $\Box$

**Note:** In fact, this is also equivalent to being projective, and the equivalence theorem that I am familiar with usually places all three conditions, not just the two you are dealing with.

So: assume that every surjection onto $P$ has a right inverse. In particular,  there exists a $Q$ such that $P\oplus Q$ is free.

Now assume we have a surjection $\psi\colon M\to N$ and a morphism $\phi\colon P\to N$. Let $Q$ be such that $Q\oplus P$ is free, $F$, and let $f\colon F\to N$ be given by $f(x) = \phi(\pi_P(x))$, where $\pi_P\colon Q\oplus P\to P$ is the projection onto the second coordinate. Let $B$ be a basis for $F$.

For each $b\in B$, $f(b)\in N$, hence there exists $m\in M$ such that $\psi(m)=f(b)=\phi(\pi_P(x))$. Define a map $\Theta\colon B\to M$ by $\Theta(b)=m$ for any one such choice of $m$. Since $F$ is free, this defines a (unique) morphism $\Theta\colon F\to M$. Now let $\theta\colon P\to M$ be given by $\theta(p) = \Theta(0,p)$. Then $\psi(\theta(p)) =\phi(\pi_P(0,p)) = \phi(p)$. Hence $\psi\circ\theta = \phi$, which is what we need.